# What technology to use for accessing Jira 3.13.2?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I was going to use Jira Rest Java Client for programatically access Jira from Java. This uses Jira REST API that is supported only for Jira 5.0 and later versions.

But I have Jira 3.13.2 version and I want to programatically interface with it.
On their site they have listed various technologies like REST, XML-RPC, SOAP, etc.

But I don't know what to use for my work.

Can anyone point me to the correct technology that I should use?

Comment: You could use an older version of Bob Swift's JIRA CLI or my JIRA Python CLI as starting points.

Comment: can you provide any links where I can find it.

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara In case you still need it, I found some archives at https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.jira.cli/versions the oldest version available (2.0.0) seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer using REST, but it depends on what type of app you're developing to access it and also in your case that is not applicable. But I want to talk a bit of the downsides.

For example you may have some business requirement that emposes that you use SOAP (ugh :D). 
Choosing what to use for access should be made carefully since for example the SOAP API is now deprecated - in `JIRA > 5.x` . So if you're developing something that will have to access newer versions than the one you speak of it is probably best to utilize the REST api. It is secure and easy to use. You can also have two access methods - after all these are just interfaces to the remote app and the data is the same (not it's representation) and JAVA has core SOAP capabilities with jboss if I have not mistaken. @mdoar's suggestions would get you on the way. Depending on the requrements you could also develop you app as a JIRA plugin and thus have direct access to JIRA. I'm currently developing an externall application that accesses JIRA through REST and crunches the data for management, but that's with the latest JIRA ver and REST in PHP.

A brief intoruction to the REST API could be found [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs) and the full REST API documentation is [here](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) (this is for the latest version). Utiliing the REST API is as easy as making GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests.

Hope this was helpfull, but I think I got a bit carried off.

Comment: I have been playing with Jira Web API since last week and find it really powerful. It is easy to manage almost everything from there. One thing I just haven't been able to do is the user and group management. Do you have any idea how to accomplish that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @coffekid I have never used the API for user/group management however there are some endpoints:
[here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#idp2111184) and 
[here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#idp2003536)
but nothing to manage them..
Ask your question over at [Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/)